# mysql - conditionals with joins - only distinct rows

Tags: mysql, sql

Sorry for not precise subject. More precise description is here:
Consider example tables:

City:

```
cityId  | cityName
----------------------
51      | NY
52      | Chicago
53      | SanFrancisco
```

People:

```
peopleId | peopleName | 
-----------------------
21        | John      |  
22        | Emma      | 
23        | Frank     | 
24        | George    | 
25        | Albert    |
```

Goods:

```
goodsId | good   | peopleId  | cityId
------------------------------------
1       | bread  |  21       |  51
2       | steel  |  22       |  51
3       | onion  |  23       |  0 
4       | chair  |  22       |  52
5       | knife  |  22       |  0
```

Input data: 
cityId: 51
peopleId: (21, 22, 23, 25)

Expected result:

```
peopleId | peopleName | cityId | cityName | goodId | good
-----------------------------------------------------------
   21    | John       |  51    |  NY      |   1    | bread
   22    | Emma       |  51    |  NY      |   2    | steel 
   23    | Frank      |  0     |  ---     |   3    | onion
   25    | Albert     |  ---   |  ---     |  ---   | ----
   22    | Emma       |  0     |  ---     |   5    | knife
```

Even if there is almost empty data still some row is displayed (here peopleId 25). What is going on here?

I want to select all the goods.good that have people.peopleId in input data (21, 22, 23, 25) and cityId = 51. However not every row in goods table have specified goods.cityId, and also not every goods.peopleId is in goods table. I want my result to be conditionally dependent:

- if peopleId exists in goods table and this row have also cityId i am looking - print it.
- else if peopleId exists in goods table but goods.cityId = 0 - select it.
- else if peopleId doesnt exist in goods table - print only peopleId and peopleName, rest of the fields leave empty.

I already made this:

```
SELECT DISTINCT people.peopleId, people.peopleName, 
CASE 
   WHEN goods.cityId = 51
       THEN (SELECT goods.good FROM goods WHERE goods.zalozenie = 51 AND goods.peopleId = people.peopleId)
       ELSE 

CASE 
       WHEN goods.cityId = 0
       THEN (SELECT goods.good FROM goods WHERE goods.cityId = 0 AND goods.peopleId = people.peopleId)
ELSE -1
END 
END AS goods FROM people LEFT JOIN goods ON people.peopleId = goods.peopleId  WHERE people.peopleId IN ( 21, 22, 23, 25 )
```

This works almost fine but result shows:

```
peopleId | peopleName | cityId | cityName | goodId | good
-----------------------------------------------------------
   21    | John       |  51    |  NY      |   1    | bread
   22    | Emma       |  51    |  NY      |   2    | steel 
   23    | Frank      |  0     |  ---     |   3    | onion
   25    | Albert     |  ---   |  ---     |  ---   | ----
   22    | Emma       |  0     |  ---     |   5    | knife
```

Unwanted row is the last one - it should only select second line and ignore last one if peopleId = 22 with cityId > 0 is already on result.
Hope you can help me!

Kalreg

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you are trying to do something like this:

```
SELECT p.peopleId, p.peopleName, c.cityId, c.cityName, g.goodId, g.good
FROM people p left join goods g
    on p.peopleId = g.peopleId
  left join city c
    on c.cityId = g.cityId
WHERE  
  (g.goodId is null or g.cityId = 51 or (g.cityId = 0 and NOT EXISTS (SELECT * FROM goods g2 WHERE g2.peopleId=p.peopleId and g2.cityId>0)))
  and p.peopleId IN (21, 22, 23, 25);
```

See this [sql fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/e90d7/6/0) to play around with it a bit. Hopefully that's a starting point, anyway.

Comment: Thank you for your post. Although it works in fiddle i can not adapt it to my project, somehow it doesnt work, however i accept the answer. In my project i used original query and filtered it in php. i dont like this way but it works

Comment: If you have more information about your actual project, I'd be happy to try to help you adapt it.